# How do I create a note using the Evernote gem in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, evernote

I am using the [Evernote gem](https://github.com/cgs/evernote) in my Ruby on Rails app.

I am creating a NoteStore by doing this:

```
# Construct the URL used to access the user's account
noteStoreUrl = "https://sandbox.evernote.com/edam/note/" + shard_id
noteStoreTransport = Thrift::HTTPClientTransport.new(noteStoreUrl)
noteStoreProtocol = Thrift::BinaryProtocol.new(noteStoreTransport)
noteStore = Evernote::EDAM::NoteStore::NoteStore::Client.new(noteStoreProtocol)
```

I can access the users' notes fine. My question is, how do I create a [note object?](http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/ref/Types.html#Struct_Note)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling:

```
note = Evernote::EDAM::Type::Note.new()
note.title = "Test note from ENTest.rb"
note.content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' +
  '<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">' +
  '<en-note>Here is the Evernote logo:<br/>'
createdNote = noteStore.createNote(authToken, note)
```

In the evernote official ruby app that's how they construct the note.